# Tossing a coin.

Tags: probability

We are tossing a coin. The probability of head is $p$, and probability tail is $1-p$ 
We would like to find probability that we have to toss $> 150$ times to get $10$ heads.

So, my partial solution is:

Lex $X$ be a number of tosses to get 10 heads. 
Then, $$P(X>150) = 1 - P(X \le 150) = 1 - \sum_{n=10}^{150} \binom n {10} p^{10}(1-p)^{n-10}  $$

And:

1) I don't know how to get result. ( We can assume that we know p)

2) My idea is OKAY?

3) Perhaps you have a better idea.
Please help me.

Comment: We want the probability that in $150$ tosses we have $9$ or fewer heads. Straight binomial problem.  Your sum does some double counting.

Comment: why you compute P(X≤150) that we don't get 10 head? I highlight that we should compute probability that we MUST toss >150 times to get 10 heads.

Comment: We **must** toss $\gt 150$ times precisely if the first  $150$ tosses don't get us enough heads.

Comment: You right. So the answer is: $\sum^9_{k=0}\binom {150}{k} p^k (1-p)^{150-k}.$$ But how to compute it? I know p. Maybe Poisson?

Comment: Nowadays, software, and even some calculators, easily deal with $\binom{150}{k}$ for small $k$. In the old days, one would use the Poisson approximation if $150p$ is of modest size, and the normal approximation, perhaps with continuity correction, for $150p$ and and $150(1-p)$ largish, say bigger than $10$.

Comment: so what should be answer to this task. Let assume that n is much bigger than 150 and k = 30. p = 0,01

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22036/discussion-between-user180834-and-andre-nicolas).

Comment: Sorry, after a couple of unpleasant experiences about $3$ years ago, I have avoided chat. Your question is not completely clear. If you make $n$ and $p$ explicit, and want to know how to efficiently compute a certain quantity (perhaps approximately) that might be worth asking in a new question. Please give context, and what you have tried, to make sure that the question does not get closed.

Answer (score 4):

To compute $P(X\leq 150)$ you just have to sum up the probabilities that you have 0 head to 9 head in 150 tosses.
i.e.
$\sum_{k=0}^{9}{150 \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{150-k}$